# Video Tag plugin for Octopress denies access

Tags: frameworks, octopress

The documentation provides the following syntax:

```
{% video url/to/video [width height] [url/to/poster] %}
```

I created `/source/videos/test.mp4` and made a call to it like this:

```
{% video /videos/test.mp4 %}
```

I get the videoplayer to appear loaded on the web page (the first screen image did not load), but when the `play` button is pressed the following error is generated:

```
Video not found or access denied: /videos/test.mp4
```

Changing the url to `source/videos/test.mp4` and even the complete path from `~/` did not solve the issue.

There is no documentation to set the video path in the `config.rb` file but I did the following with no success:

```
videos_dir = "source/videos"
```

Also, using the example provided in the documentation worked fine, but this used a call to `http://` and I'd like to call a file in an application directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the plugin to work, but not under `localhost:4000`. For reasons I don't comprehend, the plugin works with `pow`, but not with `rake preview`

Comment: due to the dynamic nature of this project, it was probably better to post this on the issues page of its github home.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache, with apache works without problems.